# @font-face src file not working for multiple languages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to include fonts for both english and tamil languages in my application. Currently, the `.ttf` file changing only for english letters not for tamil letters.

Any solution(s) for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check if your font-file supports tamil letters? It could be that that font only contains English characters. Add your code to the question please and the font you want to use.

Comment: I am using this, `@font-face { font-family: "SomeFont"; src: url("~/fonts/SomeFontTTF") format("truetype"); }`. And I have separate font files for tamil and english letters. Can't we have one single font file for both tamil and english letters?

Comment: I think it depends on what the font file contains and to the best of my knowledge I don't think most fonts have **both** English and Tamil characters. You have to open the font file and [check its contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arpTa.png). IF you have two separate font files you have to use separate `@font-face` rules for **each** font. See this [example google font](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,300italic,600,600italic,800) - Just focus on the different `@font-face` rules and not their contents

Comment: That example google font is working for both tamil and english letters. Are using separate font files for multiple languages a better option? If not, can you suggest me some options to download(purchase/free) for single font file which supports multiple languages?